# React state isn't being changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to react and I'm trying to create a log in authentication system and so far it works apart from one thing. The problem is when I use the sign out function which should change the authentication state to false, it fails to do so. I've just read that state changes are asynchronous so now I'm confused what order things are being executed as I have two useEffects too. The desired outcome is that the authentication can be set to false and the username and password to empty strings so that when I refresh the page I stay signed out. (right now it appears I'm signed out as the sign in page is rendered yet when I refresh it doesn't render, and if I type in /home, it works and my user is what I signed in as). Any help or pointers would be appreciated

I'll put the code I struggle with at the start and then the whole file for reference at the bottom

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';




function App() {


// these are the usernames and their corresponding passwords which //will be used for the authentication 

  var users = {
    "sebastian": "password",
    "henry": "hoover",
    "guest": "guest",
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState({username: "", password: ""})


  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  
 
  const Logout = () => {
      setIsAuth(false);
      setUser({
        username: "",
        password: "", 
          })
      console.log(isAuth);

      console.log(user.username + "is the username state after logout and password: " + user.password);
      navigate('/Login');
  }

// log returns "henry is the username state after logout and //password: hoover


  
// two use effects which worked to keep me signed in, not signed out
  useEffect(() => {
    let u = localStorage.getItem("userUsername");
    let p = localStorage.getItem("userPassword");
    for (let key in users) {
      let value = users[key]
      if (u == key && p == value) {
        setIsAuth(true)
        setUser({
          username: u,
          password: p,
        }) 
        
      } else {
        setIsAuth(false);
        setUser({
          username: u,
          password: p,
        })
      }
    }
    
    
    
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {

    for (let key in users) {
      let value = users[key]

      if(user.username == key) {
        if (user.password == value) {
          setIsAuth(true);
          localStorage.setItem("userUsername", user.username);
          localStorage.setItem("userPassword", user.password);
          console.log(user.username);
          console.log(user.password);
          console.log("oh no");
          
          
        } else {
          setIsAuth(false);
          localStorage.setItem("userUsername", "");
          localStorage.setItem("userPassword", "");
          
        }
      } 
      
      
    }
  },[user])

  
  
  return (

    <div className="App">
      
      
      <Routes>    
        {isAuth ? 
          <Route path="/Home" element={<><Header Logout={Logout}/><Home user={user}/></>}/> :
         
        
//inside the header component is where the sign out is called after //pressing a button 
          
      </Routes>        
    </div>
     
 
    
  );
}

export default App;

//THE HEADER COMPONENT RELEVANT CODE ONLY

import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const Header = ({Logout}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)


  const signout = () => {
    Logout();
  }

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signout();
}
  return (
    <div className='header'>
      
        <ul>
     
     
          <li>
            <Link to={'/'} onClick={submitHandler}>Sign Out</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header



// THE WHOLE FILE

import Intro from './components/Intro';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Header from './components/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer } from 'react-dom';
import { type } from '@testing-library/user-event/dist/type';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';



function App() {

  const guestUser = {
    username: "guest",
    password: "guest",
  }

  var users = {
    "sebastian": "password",
    "henry": "hoover",
    "guest": "guest",
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState({username: "", password: ""})
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [test, setTest] =useState("");



  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  const Login = details => {
    console.log(details);
    for (let key in users) {
      let value = users[key]

      if(details.username == key) {
        console.log("username matches, checking password");
        if (details.password == value) {
          console.log("password matches signed in");
          setIsAuth(true);
          setUser({username: key, password: value})
          navigate('/home');
        } else {
          console.log("details do not match");
          setError("Username and password do not match");
        }
      }
      
    }
  }

 
  const Logout = () => {
      setIsAuth(false);
      setUser({
        username: "",
        password: "", 
          })
      console.log(isAuth);

      console.log(user.username + "after logout and " + user.password);
      navigate('/Login');
  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    let u = localStorage.getItem("userUsername");
    let p = localStorage.getItem("userPassword");
    for (let key in users) {
      let value = users[key]
      if (u == key && p == value) {
        setIsAuth(true)
        setUser({
          username: u,
          password: p,
        }) 
        
      } else {
        setIsAuth(false);
        setUser({
          username: u,
          password: p,
        })
      }
    }
    
    
    
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {

    for (let key in users) {
      let value = users[key]

      if(user.username == key) {
        if (user.password == value) {
          setIsAuth(true);
          localStorage.setItem("userUsername", user.username);
          localStorage.setItem("userPassword", user.password);
          console.log(user.username);
          console.log(user.password);
          console.log("oh no");
          
          
        } else {
          setIsAuth(false);
          localStorage.setItem("userUsername", "");
          localStorage.setItem("userPassword", "");
          
        }
      } 
      
      
    }
  },[user])

  
  
  return (

    <div className="App">
      
      
      <Routes>    
        {isAuth ? 
          <Route path="/Home" element={<><Header Logout={Logout}/><Home user={user}/></>}/> :
          <Route path="/Login" element={<Intro Login={Login} error={error}/>}/>}
        
        
        <Route path="" element={isAuth ? <Navigate to ="/Home" /> :
          <Navigate to ="/Login"/>}/>
          
      </Routes>        
    </div>
     
 
    
  );
}

export default App;

//HEADER WHOLE FILE 

import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { MenuOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons'
import { Close } from '@material-ui/icons'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const Header = ({Logout}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  const showMenu = () => {
    setActive(!active)
  }

  const signout = () => {
    Logout();
  }

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signout();
}
  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <div className='menu-icon'>
        <MenuOutlined className='menu' onClick={showMenu}/>
      </div>
      <nav className={active ? 'slider active' : 'slider'}>
        <ul>
          <div className='closed'>
            <Close className='close' onClick={showMenu}/>

          </div>
          <li>
            <Link to={'/'}>Create Microreactor</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={'/'}>View Microreactors</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={'/'} onClick={submitHandler}>Sign Out</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: first of all, you don't need two useEffect. useEffect with no dependancies runs the very first time the component is rendered. Everytime you refresh useEffect gets executed. There are plenty of components used in the above given code. Can you post a reusable code with only the ones you needed to be sorted out. And you will have to execute the setState upon an action and set the desired value. Like button onClick={logout} function. where logout contains setState.

Comment: Please take a look again, I tried to edit it to make it shorter but kept the whole files for reference at the end, it keeps me stuck in a logged in state, even when I sign out I'm stuck, the console log in the sign out functions shows the states which will sign me out never change hence why I'm stuck signed in

Comment: what you need is library to control global state that you can control in one place like Redux. In general, useState hook in react should just keep states of local variables.  A login auth/functioning app should use global state.

Comment: isn't redux a bit overkill just for an authentication system? I started learning react 2 weeks ago and don't want to get overwhelmed

Comment: If you wanted to exercise with an authentication system use firebase or make an asynchronous mockup. This sort of exercise doesn't make sense imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, I only needed 1 use effect to not complicate things and instead of changing a state to decide if I was authenticated or not, I changed a variable, and if that variable was changed, then I would proceed to change the state. I did that because the state changes are asynchronous and won't be updated in the same scope or function if your later code depends on the state being changed earlier in the same function.

```
import Intro from './components/Intro';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Header from './components/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer } from 'react-dom';
import { type } from '@testing-library/user-event/dist/type';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';



function App() {

  const guestUser = {
    username: "guest",
    password: "guest",
  }

  const users = {
    "sebastian": "password",
    "henry": "hoover",
    "guest": "guest",
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState({username: "", password: ""})
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [test, setTest] =useState("");



  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  const Login = details => {
    console.log(details);
    for (const key in users) {
      const value = users[key]

      if(details.username == key) {
        if (details.password == value) {
          setIsAuth(true);
          setUser({username: key, password: value});
          localStorage.setItem("userUsername", details.username);
          localStorage.setItem("userPassword", details.password);
          navigate('/home');
        } else {
          setError("Username and password do not match");
        }
      }
      
    }
  }

 
  const Logout = () => {
    setIsAuth(false);
    setUser({
      username: "",
      password: "", 
    })
    localStorage.setItem("userUsername", "");
    localStorage.setItem("userPassword", "");
    authenticated = false;
    
    navigate('/Login');
  }
  

  let authenticated = false

  useEffect(() => {
    const u = localStorage.getItem("userUsername");
    const p = localStorage.getItem("userPassword");
    for (const key in users) {
      const value = users[key]
      if (key == u && value == p) {
        user.username = u;
        user.password = p;
        authenticated = true;

      }
      
    }
    
    (authenticated && setIsAuth(true));

  }, []

  )

  
  return (

    <div className="App">
      
      
      <Routes>    
        {isAuth ? 
          <Route path="/Home" element={<><Header Logout={Logout}/><Home user={user}/></>}/> :
          <Route path="/Login" element={<Intro Login={Login} error={error}/>}/>}
        
        
        <Route path="" element={isAuth ? <Navigate to ="/Home" /> :
          <Navigate to ="/Login"/>}/>
          
      </Routes>        
    </div>
     
 
    
  );
}

export default App;
```